# Samsung voice recordings won't play on iOS but recordings from other Android devices do play on iOS

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I've written a Android module for an App which required a way to make a voice recording. The app is cross-platform and thus required a way to record and play cross-platform, the only problem is that a recording made with a Samsung device doesn't play on iOS but other devices (OnePlus 3 & Nexus 7) do play on iOS even though there is no difference in the way the file is processed as far as I know. Does someone have experience with this or is able to help me out?

Comment: Did you check the file format and the encoders used to prepare the voice files? Maybe the codec is not supported by iOS, the one which Samsung uses?

Comment: I don't know very much about the codecs used by Samsung or Apple but the codec used is defined in Java and I don't really know if the codec is different per device, which I can assume is. But not that it really matters anymore since I'm now using FFMPEG to convert the files over to .mp3 to see if that works. Thanks for the suggestion tho!

Comment: Let us know your finding as it will help the community

Comment: If everything goes well I'll post the results!